# Having trouble interpreting what the question asks about geometric distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a problem that says "Automobiles arrive at a vehicle equipment inspetion station according to a Poisson process with a rate $\alpha=10$ per hour. Suppose that with probability $.5$ an arriving vehicle will have no equipment violations.

a) What is the probability that exactly ten arrive during the hour and al ten have no violations?

b) For any fixed $y\ge 10$, what is the probability that $y$ arrive during the hour, of which ten have no violations?

c) What is the probability that ten "no-violation" cars arrive during the next hour?

All $3$ sound so similar to me but I know they aren't the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can help a lot to try to write the descriptions as probabilities, then see how you can manipulate them into something related to the given distributions.

For example, let's call the number of cars arriving in a given hour $N$, which we know is distributed Poisson($\alpha=10$), and the number with no violations $M_N\sim Binomial(N, 0.5)$. Notice that the distribution of $M_N$ depends on $N$.

So the first question asks for the joint probability of having 10 cars show up, and for none of them to have violations, ie. $P(N=10,M=10)$. We can rearrange that to get $P(N=10,M_N=10)=P(N=10)*P(M_N=10|N=10)$, i.e. the probability we get exactly 10 vehicles, multiplied by the probability that 10 vehicles have no violations *given* there are exactly 10 vehicles.

Question (b) is a little trickier, but if you look closely it's specifying a number of vehicles (y) and a number of no-violation vehicles (10), so we can use a similar expression - $P(N=y,M_N=10)=P(N=y)*P(M_N=10|N=y)$. In other words, what is the probability that $y$ vehicles show up, and then given that $y$ vehicles have arrived, that exactly 10 of them have no violations?

Question (c) takes it one step further - regardless of the number of vehicles that show up, what is the probability that exactly 10 of them have no violations? You can't compute that directly, but your answer to (b) should give you a hint. Namely, we're trying to find $P(M_N=10)$ without knowing $N$, but to do that we can think of it as a bunch of scenarios - the probability that 10 vehicles show up and none have violations, or that 11 vehicles show up and 10 have no violations, or that 12 show up and 10 have no violations ... and since all of these are mutually exclusive events, we can write that as the sum of the individual probabilities, i.e. $P(M_N=10)=P(N=10)P(M_N=10|N=10)+P(N=11)P(M_N=10|N=11)+P(N=12)P(M_N=10|N=12)+...$, which you should be able to put into sigma notation and then fill in using your answer from (b).

Comment: Thanks, those were some of the ideas I had but I wasn't entirely positive.